# Avoiding duplicates when storing NSUserDefaults (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, duplicates, nsuserdefaults

What is the best way to save my data to NSUserDefaults avoiding duplicate entries? Here is what I am now doing in viewWillAppear. I am storing individual entries of dictionary data. I don't know if this is the best way and advice is appreciated as well as info on how to avoid dups.

```
//
// Keep track of photos that have been viewed by storing the photo data in NSUserDefaults.
//
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *recentlyViewed = [[defaults objectForKey:RECENTLY_VIEWED_KEY] mutableCopy];
if (!recentlyViewed) recentlyViewed = [NSMutableArray array];        
[recentlyViewed addObject:self.imageDict];

//
// Keep only MAX number of recently viewed photos.
//
while (recentlyViewed.count > RECENTLY_VIEWED_MAX) {
    [recentlyViewed removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}

//
// Write the array back to NSUserDefaults and synchronize it.
//
[defaults setObject:recentlyViewed forKey:RECENTLY_VIEWED_KEY];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to make sure duplicates aren't being stored, The most greedy and easy way of doing it (not the most efficient for large amounts of data) is:

```
 1. Get the current values from NSUserDefault into a NSMutableArray
 2. Check in a for loop if any of the values from the NSMutableArray match with the value you are trying to save. 
 3. If it does, replace the old value with new (or don't do anything)
 4. Save the NSMutableArray back to NSUserDefault.
```

This is how I would do it, but wouldn't suggest for big values. If you are doing it on the main thread and it takes more than 5 seconds, the application would be killed.